# How to move login page when session expired

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I have multiple screens and api's, if session expired each api get **session expired** message. Based in that I'm moving from current page to login page.

My code :

```
//If session expaired move to login page
if message == "Session Expired" {
      //Session Expired
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
         let lpc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LVC")
         //Set the user login key false 
         UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
         //Clear user defaults
         SharedClass.sharedInstance.clearDataFromUserDefaults()
         self.navigationController?.pushViewController(lpc!, animated: false)
      }
}
```

Here I'm using ** pushViewController** to navigate back. Every thing working fine, but when i'm in **Nth VC** is session expired it's navigating **N times** to login page. Means if I'm navigating from 1st VC to 2nd VC, 2nd VC to 33rd VC, 3rd VC to 4th, is session expired in 4th VC it's navigating to login page around 3times. How to resolve this issue....

Comment: You can set login as root controller again and empty your navigation stack.

Comment: @ Sharad Chauhan, can you please suggest code...

Comment: @ Sharad Chauhan, see my answer is ti correct tor not

Answer (score 0):

use the following:

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
```

if login is not root,then you can use the following:

```
if let controllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers, controllers.count > 0{
        for vc in controllers{
            if vc is LoginViewController{
                self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc, animated: false)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank you login page is not my root view controller

Comment: getting error `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'UIViewController' `

Comment: My bad it needed the instance of viewcontroller and I passed the id only, try the edited part now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LVC")
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([vc], animated: true)
```

Comment: you please see my answer and is it correct or not please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide your full code so I am not sure why that issue happens. However, here are 2 solutions to achieve your requirement.

- First implementation: [Image for 1st flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw2oR.png)

If the user logged in:

```
navigationController?.viewControllers = [loggedInVC]
```

If the user doesn't login yet or when he/she logout:

```
navigationController?.viewControllers = [logInVC]
```

- 2nd implementation: [Image for 2nd flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFHV3.png)

LoginVC is the root view controller and acts as a loading screen, and only show the login form when the session is invalid. With this implementation, every time the session is invalid. You can call:

```
navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

to navigate the user back to the login screen.

Answer (score 0):

First create the global variable to access the AppDelegate, because we are putting redirection function here.

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

Now put below function in AppDelegate to set login screen whenever your session is expired.

```
func configureWindow(_ viewController: UIViewController) {    
        if let window = window {
            window.rootViewController = viewController
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

now set your login UIViewController as like below.

```
let loginVC = LoginViewController()
appDelegate.configureWindow(loginVC)
```

Comment: you please see my answer and is it correct or not please tell me

Comment: Don't push loginVC in navigation controller, try to clear the navigation stack and set it to first position.

Comment: if you are setting your viewcontroller in window rootViewController then no need to pop controller just set controller to window

Comment: `self.navigationController!.viewControllers.removeAll() let lvc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LVC") as! LoginViewController let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = lvc`.   is this correct. and I'm getting error `Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7fb840800600> on <******: 0x7fb840069800> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
`. how to solve this....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is this right or wrong. But i'm getting one more issue

1) First i cleared all navigations from navigation stack

2) Then i made my LoginVC as  Root VC

3) Finally i called **popToRootViewController**

```
//If session expaired move to login page
if message == "Session Expired" {
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
      //Check navigation stacks
      let navigationArray = self.navigationController?.viewControllers //To get all UIViewController stack as Array
      print(navigationArray!)//Prints navigation stacks
      //Remove all
      self.navigationController!.viewControllers.removeAll()
      //Check navigation stacks
      let navigationArray2 = self.navigationController?.viewControllers //To get all UIViewController stack as Array
      print(navigationArray2 as Any)//Prints nill

      //Check whether the user logined or not
      UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
      //Clear user defaults
      SharedClass.sharedInstance.clearDataFromUserDefaults()

      let lvc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LVC") as! LoginViewController
      let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
      appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = lvc

  }
}

//Call alert function
self.showAlert(title: "", msg: message)
```

I don't know is this right or wrong. But i'm getting one more issue

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7fb840800600> on <******: 0x7fb840069800> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```